# How can I force a user to navigate to the sub-task and checkmark checkboxes in the ticket description before changing the ticket status into Done?

Tags: jira, jira-automation

I am implementing a Jira workflow with Stories. Each story contains two or more sub-tasks, each of them containing a checklist that should be checkmarked before the status can be changed into "Done".
The problem is that the developers don't look into the subtask but read only the title and change the status to Done from the Story.

Is there a way so that I can "force" developers open the sub-task and do an action (i.e. checkmark checkboxes) before changing the ticket status?

Expected result:

1. Open story
2. From the story, developer navigates to the sub-task
3. Checkmark checkboxes (checkboxes can be in the description or can be a field apart)
4. From the sub-task or from the story, developer can mark the sub-task as Done after marking all checkboxes

I tried to add field Checkbox in Subtask and make it required

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you are using any plugins but the idea behind this should be as following:

1. Add a condition to the task (Story)'s workflow (to the transition to Done) which indicates something like "Can't move it to Done until all subtasks are closed"
   P.S. You can do it with [JWT](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/29496/jira-workflow-toolbox?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) or [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)
2. In the Sub-task's workflow (at the transition to Done) make the checkbox values required.
3. (Optional) For UX, add a post function to the workflow and trigger "Transition Story to Done" when all sub-tasks are closed.

Comment: Hello @stuck thanks for your fast reply. The problem is that you can change the status also from the Story and are not required to navigate to the subtask which is what I want to force our developers to do and unfortunately making the checkbox values required does not do the trick.

Comment: If you put condition to Story (Bullet 1), developer cannot close the ticket; so he/she manually will go to the sub-task and close it.